# Is it Possible to assign a Class Paramter to Pandas pivot_table Method Value Parameter

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to use a class parameter in my pandas pivot_table method at values. But I'm getting key error. 
Is this usage right? Or what I'm doing wrong. Thanks.

```
 def pvt_table(self):
    for value, df in self.time_series_values_to_df.items():
        df_pvt = pd.pivot_table(df, index=DataPrep.date_param, values=self.pvt_value, aggfunc='sum')
        df_pvt = self.populate_rows(df_pvt)
        self.time_series_values_to_df_pvt[value] = df_pvt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem with your input data types:

- The function DataFrame.items() returns (object, **pd.Series**).
- pd.pivot_table() only works with **pd.DataFrame** as data.

Otherwise, the usage of a class attribute should be fine.